# How to disable forwarding message sent by Telegram Bot in private chat?

Tags: chat, telegram-bot, private, forwarding, disable

How to disable forwarding message of Telegram Bot in private chat?

Some individuals are receiving messages from the bot and subsequently distributing them to others.

I want to prevent this activity
I am using javascript with TelegramBot library.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You must set protect_content to true. Then the ability of users to save, copy and share messages with others will be disabled.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

[image]